# How can I upload a file to my ruby on rails app using curl CLI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, file-upload, curl

On the web side of things, I have two fields: name, and document. Document is a file field, and name is just what the user wants to call the file in the app.

Here is what I have tried:

```
curl -F "media[document]=@a.png" -F "media[name]=api" "http://example.com/medias/create.xml?api_key=123"
```

but I get an InvalidAuthenticityToken Error.
This error only occurs when I try to upload a file / make a media object. The other API / xml commands work (the ones not involving files)

what is the correct way to upload a file using cURL?

EDIT:
adding -H "Content-Type: application/xml" to the above curl command make the server generate this error:

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Tue Jan 24 08:45:03 -0500 2012
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  #<REXML::ParseException: malformed XML: missing tag start
Line: 
Position: 
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
<:??OH?ɽ?H? ???g??yx~t????op?.$?????P&W ??"?
```

normally the XML is supplied using the -d argument. but I don't think files can be included in xml? maybe they can? idk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create file from xml, you should format your xml to use [data](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-cdata/), either [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and/or [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp), depending of your needs. Once you have a corretly formatted xml file, you just have to send it with curl.

If you just want to upload file, you don't need to use an xml interface. You can just call :

```
curl -F "media[document]=@./a.png;type=image/png" -F "media[name]=api" "http://example.com/medias/
```

For your authentification problem, if you still have it on this url (I do not encounter it on a new rails 3.2.1 fresh app), you can access it with a regular browser, get the cookie information and send it with curl. It means that you will add to your command :

```
--cookie "csrf-param=authenticity_token" --cookie "csrf-value=XXXXXXX"
```

Or use a [convenient script](http://slacy.com/blog/2010/02/using-cookies-sqlite-in-wget-or-curl/) to send all your current Firefox cookies from an host into curl.

Answer (score 3):

Rails uses [authenticity token](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures) to prevent [CSRF](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf). It inserts special token calculated based on current user's session into every form and checks it when request comes to the server.

When you perform POST request using curl you get that error as you're not passing valid authenticity token to the server. You can either disable that protection for you method like that (note, that disabling it will make this action vulnerable for CSRF):

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :some_action
```

or you can use some [ninja](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/3035393350/curling-with-rails-authenticity-token) [magic](http://www.maximporges.com/2011/03/02/using-curl-with-a-web-site-secured-by-rails-authenticity-token/) to pass valid authenticity token to the server.

Another option is based on the fact that Rails checks authenticity token only for requests with certain content types. If it's an API and you're getting response in JSON you can try setting content type of the request to `application/json` like that:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" ...
```

See these links for more information: [one](http://www.darianshimy.com/2009/10/invalidauthenticitytoken-error-in-rails/), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1608563/357743), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/349969/357743).

Comment: but I'm using an API key... shouldn't that handle the authentication for me?

Comment: this doesn't work with the -F tag in CURL. can you provide the proper syntax to upload the file with the json or xml content type?

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable authenticity token for the action. Use this in your controller (I'm assuming the action is named `create`):

```
protect_from_forgery :except => [:create]
```

This only happens with POST, PUT or DELETE requests, that's probably why other request are successful.

If this is an API you will want to disable this entirely. You can remove `protect_from_forgery` in you `ApplicationController`.

The authenticity token is used to (somewhat) ensure that the user goes through the form when modifying resources. The application creates a random token associated with the user session and puts it in a hidden field of the form. When the form is submitted the token is compared with the one stored in the session to made the check. This won't have any sense in an API.

Comment: it's a web app and an API. most of the other actions which use POST work. but there is just something weird with the file. I shouldn't have to disable pretect from forgery if I have an api key, right?

Comment: Well, that depends on how is implemented the api_key mechanism, it sounds as it isn't something that rails provides by default.

Comment: right, it's using restful_auth. http://www.justinbritten.com/work/2009/05/rails-api-authentication-using-restful-authentication/